# How to display wordpress blog when I type mydomainname.com/blog

Tags: wordpress

I hostestd some files under root (my hosting server is discountasp.net) and I installed wordpress only for blog purpose, when I type mydomainname.com/wordpress it is showing blog page I trayed renaming wordpress to blog its not allowing , please any one suggest me how to to make my website to display blog when I type mydomainname.com/blog

Comment: Did you try the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Created a new folder under root directory and named it as blog, Finally i have copied WordPress installation files to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

First create a new folder and name this : `blog` Then install your wordpress in this folder. It means the index page `index.php` is in this folder. Now copy this folder to main root of your website through FTP. Now when you go to this address `www.yoursitename.com/blog` then it will show the blog pages whicn installed with wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change directory name WordPress to blog
2. Export database and replace URL

   `http://www.yoursitename.com/wordpress` 
               with
   `http://www.yoursitename.com/blog`
3. Import db and login adminpanel.
4. Set Permalink Settings.